# Suppress leading space on single instance of cite

Tags: citing

How do I suppress the leading space on a citation so that I get ([1],[2]) instead of ( [1],[2]) on a single instance of cite?  The only answer I've seen so far is to

```
\usepackage[nospace,noadjust]{cite}
```

but that sets the option for all citations.  I tried

```
\cite[noadjust]{mycitationkey}
```

and it didn't work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

The option `noadjust` is defined as

```
 \DeclareOption{noadjust}{\let\cite@adjust\@empty}% Don't change spaces
```

So try making this assignemnt in a group (untested since you do not have MWE):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\noadjustcite[1]{\bgroup
   \let\cite@adjust\@empty
   \cite{#1}%
\egroup}
\makeatother
```

...

```
\cite{one}, \noadjustcite{two,three}...
```